# bootstrap card change border color on hover

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add border color change effect on hover, on boostrap cards.

```
<b-card no-body class="my-card border">
    <button>Click here</button>

    <b-collapse>
      <b-card-body>
         <b-card-text>text here</b-card-text>
      </b-card-body>
    </b-collapse>
<b-card>
```

I tried to change the b-card border color using CSS class that I made, but it didn't work.

```
.my-card:hover {
    border-color:#3E7DC0;
}
```

I also tried like this (not sure if this is correct anyway), and it didn't work also.

```
b-card:hover {
   border-color:#3E7DC0;
}
```

How to fix this? Thank you so much.

edit:
I want my card to have a grey border, and it changes to blue color whenever I hover it. I think the reason the hover doesn't work is because I put the border class in this line of code
`<b-card no-body class="my-card border">`
If I remove the `border`, the hover does work, but the initial border is gone.

update:
I finally solved the problem by adding `!important` like this

```
b-card:hover {
   border: 1px solid #3E7DC0 !important;
}
```

But I know that using `!important` is not recommended. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly want, but when I change:

```
.my-card:hover {
    border-color:#3E7DC0;
}
```

to:

```
.my-card:hover {
    border: 2px solid #3E7DC0;
}
```

something else changes.
What I think you want:

```
  <div class="test1">
      <b-card no-body class="my-card border">
          <button>Click here</button>
    
          <b-collapse>
              <b-card-body>
                  <b-card-text>text here</b-card-text>
              </b-card-body>
          </b-collapse>
      <b-card>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.test1:hover {
  border: 2px solid #3E7DC0;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted. I'm not so experienced myself, but if I can, I'd love to help you out.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've tried using your method but it doesn't work :( I've added some explanation in my question, maybe you can check that out :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your css:

```
b-card:hover {
   border: 1px solid #3E7DC0 !important;
}
```

removed !important and everything works the same for me. It's probably overwritted by other CSS, !important will prevent it from being overwritten then.

If you show me all your html and css, maybe I can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.my-card:hover {
    border:1px solid #3E7DC0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but it still doesn't override my initial border color :(

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `border` class and add border on `.my-card` class

Like this

```
.my-card{
   border:1px solid gray;
 }

.my-card:hover{
   border-color:blue;
 }
```